# Modify a __main__.variable from inside a module given the name of the variable as string

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, exec, program-entry-point

I am writing a module, which contains a function f(string).
A substring of string is the name of a variable that is in **main** and that I need to modify it so that the modifications are visible in **main**.

How can I do this without actually passing the variable to the function?
(The string is a SQL-like query, and the substring is a table name).

For now, I have only found a very ugly way involving modifying the **builtin** vars…
I have tried a lot of stuff involving `exec`, but nothing was able to change the variable in **main** spacename.

I have looked at different discussions, but wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: Why not pass the variable to the module - and then make them module return the modified value?

Comment: If you have a module "a" with a variable named "foo", then "a.foo" is the name for that variable outside of "a".  If you import a in module "b" then you can write a.foo = x.  Any code in "a" that subsequently accesses foo will get the value of x.  That this is just about the worst programming practice imaginable almost goes without saying.

Comment: 1) Why is a module depending on a variable in a script? 2) Why are you using a stand-alone variable rather than a dict you can index with the (sub)string?

Comment: Your function could do `sys.modules["__main__"].__dict__[variable_name] = new_value` . I'm not sure what you mean by "passing the variable to the function".

Comment: I found a solution, just using : `exec("__main__."+substring+"= new_value")` inside the module. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are available via `sys.modules`. You could set the variable there.

```
def set_module_var(module_name, variable_name, value):
    #sys.modules["__main__"].__dict__[name] = value
    setattr(sys.modules[module_name], variable_name, value)

def f(string):
    variable_name, value = do_some_magic(string)
    set_module_var('__main__', variable_name, value)
```